# how to get an NTLM authentication through jython script in maximo

Tags: jython, maximo

trying to get a NTLM connection but my jython is not proficient enough to translate Authenticator part of the code. what information do i need to accomplish this? if this is even possible to do in jython.

```
from java.net import Authenticator
from java.net import PasswordAuthentication
from java.net import URL
from java.net import HttpURLConnection
from java.lang import StringBuilder
from java.io import InputStream, BufferedReader
from java.io import InputStreamReader

url = ""
domain = ""
user = ""
pswd = ""

'''Authenticator.setDefault( new Authenticator() {
@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(domain + "\\" + user, pswd.toCharArray());
    }
});
'''

urlReq = URL(url)

con = urlReq.openConnection()
con.setRequestMethod("GET")

res = StringBuilder()

s = con.getInputStream()
isr = InputStreamReader(s)
br = BufferedReader(isr)
ins = br.readLine()
while ins is not None:
    res.append(ins)
    ins = br.readLine()
br.close()
print("stuff:"+res.toString())
```

Comment: It might help to think "Java" instead of "Jython". Yes, your syntax is Jython, but that's it -- your libraries and available APIs are all Java. If Maximo can do it, you can too with what is available. That said, I think Maximo gets WebSphere to do that, so maybe you can get WebSphere to do it for you, too.

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing the JavaDocs for [Authenticator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html) may help here.  This should get you somewhere close to what you're looking for:

```
from java.net import Authenticator
from java.net import PasswordAuthentication
from java.net import URL
from java.net import HttpURLConnection
from java.lang import StringBuilder
from java.io import InputStream, BufferedReader
from java.io import InputStreamReader

url = ""
domain = ""
user = ""
pswd = ""

'''Authenticator.setDefault( new Authenticator() {
@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(domain + "\\" + user, pswd.toCharArray());
    }
});
'''

auth = Authenticator()
auth.PasswordAuthentication(domain + "\\" + user, pswd.toCharArray())

setDefault(auth)

urlReq = URL(url)

con = urlReq.openConnection()
con.setRequestMethod("GET")

res = StringBuilder()

s = con.getInputStream()
isr = InputStreamReader(s)
br = BufferedReader(isr)
ins = br.readLine()
while ins is not None:
    res.append(ins)
    ins = br.readLine()
br.close()
print("stuff:"+res.toString())
```